# How to create egg file using pydev plugin in eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, egg

I have used pydev with eclipse and implemented a small python project with some external source folders. now I want to execute my code on the server. in java I used to just export my project to JAR file.

can you please advice me how to do so in python.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Python what you usually do is create a setup.py with the proper structure and execute it in the command line to create what you want.

Example (taken from https://github.com/fabioz/mu-repo/)

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='mu_repo',
    version='1.0.0',
    description = 'Tool to work with multiple git repositories',
    author='Fabio Zadrozny',
    url='https://github.com/fabioz/mu-repo',
    scripts=['mu'],
    packages=['mu_repo'],
)
```

Then from the command line (or executing the module from within PyDev -- i.e.: open editor and use F9 and then edit the launch configuration to add the arguments), you can do:

> python setup.py sdist

to create your package and later:

> python setup.py sdist upload

if you want to upload to pypi

A good reference I found on the topic was: https://jamie.curle.io/blog/my-first-experience-adding-package-pypi/